# How to use pre-trained models without classes in Tensorflow?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, resnet

I'm trying to use a pretrained network such as `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50` but I have two problems:

I just want to obtain the top embedding layers at the end of the network, because I don't want to do any image classification. So due to this there is no need for a classes number I think.

- `tf.keras.applications.ResNet50` takes a default parameter `'classes=1000'`

  - Is there a way how I can omit this parameter?
- My input pictures are `128*128*1` pixels and not `224*224*3`

  - What is the best way to fix my input data shape?

My goal is to make a triplet loss network with the output of a `resnet` network.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: For the first question: You can create the whole network, load pretrained weights and then drop the last layer

Comment: For the second question: You may want to look for some modern architecture that can support any image size. (They use `Adaptive Pooling` instead of `Max Pooling`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `ResNet50` has a parameter `include_top` exactly for that purpose -- set it to `False`  to skip the last fully connected layer. (It then outputs a feature vector of length 2048).
- The best way to reduce your image size is to resample the images, e.g. using the dedicated function [`tf.image.resample_images`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/resize_images).

  - Also, I did not notice at first that your input images have only three channels, thx @Daniel. I suggest you build your 3-channel grayscale image on the GPU (not on the host using numpy) to avoid tripling your data transfer to GPU memory, using `tf.tile`:

    ```
    im3 = tf.tile(im, (1, 1, 1, 3))
    ```

Answer (score 1):

As a complement to the other answer. You will also need to make your images have three channels, although technically not the best input for Resnet, it is the easiest solution (changing the Resnet model is an option too, if you visit the source code and change the input shape yourself).

Use numpy to pack images in three channels:

```
images3ch = np.concatenate([images,images,images], axis=-1)
```